# NetBeans does not allow to push into remote GIT branch (no branch)

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control, git-push, git-commit

I'm new to GIT VCS so I'm kind of lost.

I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1 and working on PHP project with remote GIT repository.

I cloned GIT repository, during that process i checked all remote branches.

Everything went fine. Then i switched to the remote Branch 'BUG0025' did necessary code changes.

**Now It's time to Commit and Push.**

1. Commit.
   I'm doing `Git->Commit`
   It says that there are no files to commit in "Changes between HEAD and Index" section.
   All files i worked with are located in "Changes between HEAD and Working Tree" section.
   Okay.
   Pressing commit. Seems like everything went fine.
2. Push.
   I'm going to `GIT->Remote->Push`

And Boom! Here we go: [image: screenshot]

As you can see it doesn't show the branch i worked with, istead i see weird '(no branch)' branch.

It feels like even though i switched to the right branch, the local copy was not created and my commit went nowhere creating '(no branch)' branch.

If somebody could help me with this, it would be awesome!
Thank you!

Comment: Try to create a local branch pointing that remote branch

Comment: Just select one branch (the one i need to work with) during cloning? Not gonna work.